# Unable to store value in global variable JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I have a following piece of javaScript code:

```
  var ws_path = "x";
 $.get('ws.config', function(data) {

      ws_path = data;
      alert(ws_path); //alert 1
 }, 
'text');

 alert(ws_path); // alert 2



  // output = alert 1 = value of data
   //         alert 2 = x
```

I have a confusion' why it is behaving like this?

Answer (score 3):

It is because `alert(ws_path);` gets executed before the content is get from server for `ws.config` file. You need to write the code in success function of get to ensure that variable is modified after get request.

**[jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)**

Answer (score 1):

The second alert is fired before the `$.get` request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

The important point here is:

```
$.get('ws.config' ....
```

is a kind of ajax call and it takes some time to get the actual value from the server, and that anonymous function there is a callback function which gets called when the ajax call receives the response.

Here in your code if you want to have a ordered scenario you can do this:

```
var ws_path = "x";
$.get('ws.config', function(data) {
    ws_path = data;
    alert(ws_path);
    continueScenario();
}, 'text');

function continueScenario(){
    alert(ws_path);
}
```